# Draw depth works on WP7 emulator but not device

Tags: xna, c#, windows-phone-7

I am making a game on a WP7 device using C# and XNA. I have a system where I always want the object the user is touching to be brought to the top, so every time it is touched I add `float.Epsilon` to its draw depth (I have it set so that 0 is the back and 1 is the front).

On the Emulator that all works fine, but when I run it on my device the draw depths seem to be completely random.

I am hoping that anybody knows a way to fix this. I have tried doing a Clean & Rebuild and uninstalling from the device but that is no luck. My call to `spritebatch.Begin` is:

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.FrontToBack, BlendState.AlphaBlend);
```

and to draw I use

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle((int)X, (int)Y, (int)Width, (int)Height), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, SpriteEffects.None, mDrawDepth);
```

Where `mDrawDepth` is a float value of the draw depth (likely to be a very small number; a small multiple of `float.Epsilon`.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This note from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.epsilon.aspx) seems relevant:

> On ARM systems, the value of the Epsilon constant is too small to be detected, so it equates to zero. You can define an alternative epsilon value that equals 1.175494351E-38 instead.

Comment: Thank you! I know in C# you can do Class Extensions but do you know if there is a way that I could add it so that I can do something like `float.ARMEpsilon`?

Comment: I only know of extension *methods*, so you could add `float.ARMEpsilon()` (or `Single.ARMEpsilon()`) :/

Comment: After searching around and trying it out it seems you can't do static extension methods as extension methods (on an object) are already static. I've just done a `private const float` at the top of the file that uses it.